# Sporadic Clock Signals from Momentary Switch

Tags: switches, noise, clock, flipflop, debounce

I'm having trouble using a NO momentary switch to send clock edges to a J-Kbar flip flop, specifically the TI CD74AC109E([datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/schs326/schs326.pdf)).

I have a switch between +5V and the clock pin, and also added a 10k\$\Omega\$ pulldown to the clock pin, so it stays at 0V while the switch is open.

However, when I close the switch, the output responds sporadically; I have the flip flop hooked up so it toggles the Q and Qbar outputs on every high edge on the clock pin, but it doesn't always do that.

I realize that this might be caused by the lack of debouncing for the switch, but as the switch isn't a tactile switch (doesn't go click click when pressed), and the sporadic behavior occurs even when I depress the switch (open it), which makes me think it might be a different problem.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this might be happening?

P.S. [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v5YsQJk3TIE) demonstrating the issue I have. I've hooked up an LED to the Q pin to show the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All mechanical switches have the potential to bounce, and most do at least some of the time.

That's exactly what is happening. You need to add a debounce circuit. The easiest way is something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQAIy1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The RC slows the switch transition down, and the Schmitt trigger gate cleans it up so there is only one transition each way, thanks to the hysteresis.

Comment: Is this likely though? I set this idea to the side because the behavior could be observed when I slowly opened the switch, which is weird because the flip flop operates on a up clock. Also because I didn't have a schmitt trigger handy... might have to grab a couple to figure this out.

Comment: @user3052786 If it flips back and forth you can get high and low transitions on every opening or closing of the switch. Even sub-microsecond transitions will be detected by the flip-flop clock. Closing tends to be more noisy, but both can have bounce.

Comment: It's actually a momentary push button that doesn't even click. I don't understand how a low transition would trigger the flip flop which only responds to high transitions, am I missing something? Does opening the switch cause a high transition sometimes?

Comment: Yes, each time it closes or opens it can bang back and forth a few times between open and closed. So if it opens you don't get a clock, but then it closes again (clock) and then opens (no clock), so you get one false clock.

Comment: I had an extra flip flop and used that to debounce a spdt switch I had, and it worked flawlessly. You were right, after all :)

Answer (score 0):

Any mechanical switch can bounce, and the symptoms you describe are consistent with that. Debounce the switch. There are many ways to do that, I'll let you do the search.